# Can I get VS Code to syntax-highlight JsRender templates?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, jsrender

Inside a `<script type="text/x-jsrender">`, all code is displayed in white. If I just change `x-jsrender` to `html`, the syntax highlighting works as expected.

Is there a way to teach VS Code to treat `x-jsrender` like `html`?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no support OOTB, you will have to write a plugin to enable that syntax highlighting.

Comment: This answer would greatly benefit from some instructions on how to do that, given that no new functionality has to be implemented it should be fairly simple, but reading through the docs seems to imply the opposite.

Comment: @Henrik Would greatly appreciate pointers on how this, as a year later there are still no extensions that I could find.